# Simple threads example for Dev C++ using windows.h

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have been trying to learn multithreading for the first time but most of the examples I saw had a `thread.h` header file. Its not there in Dev C++.

I found [this](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/Multithreading-in-C/1/) article, which says you can do it using `windows.h`.Sadly it doesn't provide any example programs. Can somebody please provide an example program which uses thread functions in `windows.h` or any other header file which is widely used and is present in Dev C++?
Thank You

Comment: I suggest reading about _beginthreadex.
Windows provides an API called CreateThread but this causes memory leaks, due the issues with the CRT, so _beginthreadex is better and safer.

Comment: Did you consider installing Linux? It provides a standard compliant Posix threading [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/), and it has a good compiler [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) which is [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) compliant in its recent versions 4.8 & 4.9

Comment: Or if you have that C++ compliant toolchain with the C++11 compliant thread lib, belay *both* Windows threads and pthreads and just hop on that train instead.

Comment: Why not upgrade to Code::Blocks

Answer (score 2):

```
Best option is to do threading in c or c++ use pthread.h header file

example work on gcc or dev c++

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>

int i=0;
 void* fun()
{
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    printf("\nThe thread 1 is running");
}
void* van()
{
    for(i=0;i<100;i++)
    printf("\nthread 2 is running ");
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t t1,t2;
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,fun,NULL);
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,van,NULL);
    printf("\nI'm in main\n");
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `windows.h` has a function called `CreateThread().`
It's signature and other info can been seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453(v=vs.85).aspx).

You need a callback function, that will start executing when you start the thread. 
`NULL` can be passed to the first `lpThreadAttributes` argument.

```
HANDLE WINAPI CreateThread(
  _In_opt_   LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
  _In_       SIZE_T dwStackSize,
  _In_       LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE lpStartAddress,
  _In_opt_   LPVOID lpParameter,
  _In_       DWORD dwCreationFlags,
  _Out_opt_  LPDWORD lpThreadId
);
```

Comment: Worth noting that with direct use of the API-level `CreateThread` the runtime library has not been informed of the new thread, and Microsoft's runtime library does apparently not *detect* the thread.  At any rate, it insists on being informed by using its own thread creation functions. This can impact functions that rely on common state, such as heap allocation, `strtok`, date/time, error, etc.

Comment: Well the question is about thread capabilities within windows.h so don't shoot the messenger.